# Книга для самостоятельного обучения С++ в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Чтобы самостоятельно поучиться в среде Visual Studio работать. Чтобы писать Windows-приложения. Прочел для чайников С++. Все примеры консольных приложений... Может знаете что-нибудь наподобие пошаговых уроков и т.п. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Есть много нужных Вам книг. Например, прочтите "Освой самостоятельно Visual C++.NET за 21 день", автор Д. Чепмен. Там сразу идёт изучение MFC на основе диалоговых окон. Описывается всё очень понятно.

Answer (score 1):

1. "C/C++ и MS Visual C++ [номер версии среды] для начинающих" - даёт основы работы на C++ по разработке консольных приложений, графических приложений, и по работе с базами данных(!). После неё легко разбирался в среде VC++, но алгоритмическую базу следует дополнить, к примеру, следующим ресурсом.
2. От Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) представлен неплохой написанный русскими авторами бесплатный курс лекций:
   [Структуры и алгоритмы компьютерной обработки данных(MSDN)](https://www.facultyresourcecenter.com/curriculum/pfv.aspx?ID=8672&Login=)
   , в конце каждой лекции небольшое резюме, контрольные вопросы и несколько заданий на самостоятельную разработку программок. Весь код в лекциях написан на Visual C++. Название не очень многообещающее, но на самом деле там обширный курс лекций, охватывает все необходимые темы от самых основ программирования (Типы данных, указатели, работа с файлами, указатели на функции, потоки и т.д.) до динамических структур и алгоритмов сортировки. Описано очень много интересных возможностей языка, например, как создать функцию с неограниченным числом параметров.